# How do I enable Bonjour/Avahi lookups in all tools?

Tags: networking, dns, avahi, zeroconf, bonjour

Although I've got numerous Avahi packages installed, I can't seem to get something like "ping myhost.local" to resolve. But "avahi-browse --all" does return results. The device I'm trying to reach can be reached by IP address, and both the Ubuntu machine and the target device are on the same subnet.

My OS X machine, however, "ping myhost.local" works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, then first step is make sure that Personal File Sharing is enabled on your Mac. You don't say what version of Ubuntu you are using. In 14.04, you should be able to see your Mac if you go to Files > Browse Network.